# How to move elements in doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have custom list (doubly linked list and not std::list) implemented in my code. My requirement is to move the element by one left or right by updating the references.  Is it possible?

```
class Elem
{
  Elem *next;
  Elem *prev;
}
```

.......

```
void move_element_left(Elem *e)
   {
    if(e->prev()==NULL)
      return;           //Left most ... so return

    Elem *left = e->prev();

    left->next() = e->next();
    e->prev() = left->prev();

    if (left->next())
        left->next()->prev() = left;

    if (e->prev())
        e->prev()->next() = e;

    e->next() = left;
    left->prev() = e;
   }
```

.......

```
int main()
{
  ElemList ls;
  ...
  ...
  move_element_left(e);  //e of type Elem *
  ...
}
```

Above code works except for the 2nd object in the list which I want to move to left most (or to top most). (i.e. say if list(obj5, obj9, obj11, obj12,..), moving obj9 to the first in the list gives error)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Debug your code, or draw a picture and see what's going on.

Comment: @Harry Kodz You could swap values of the nodes without changing the references.:)

Comment: @Harry Kodz Also you should show how ElemList is defined.

Comment: @vsoftco  Well, he went to enroll the drawing courses.:)

Comment: @Harry Kodz, I can't find bug in this code. Could you tell me what kind of error you met? Is the null pointer, or the new head of list doesn't point to new ojb9?

Answer (score 2):

See [Bubble-sorting doubly linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151705/bubble-sorting-doubly-linked-list)

I assume your Elem class does also contain data, so move the data or - if it's a simple data pointer - swap the pointers: [C++ Swapping Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672805/c-swapping-pointers).

If that's not possible I would - from a "Don't Repeat Yourself" point of view - reuse those simple linked list functions you most probably already have:

```
void move_element_left(Elem *e)
{
    Elem *left = e->prev();

    if(left)
    {
        remove_element(e);
        insert_element_before(e, left);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Works as designed ?

Following your code in a schema, shows that it works as designed:

```
void move_element_left(Elem *e)
   {
    if(e->prev()==NULL)
      return;                  //ok ! Left most ... so return
    Elem *left = e->prev();    // ok ! (1)
    left->next() = e->next();  // ok ! (2)
    e->prev() = left->prev();  // ok ! (3)

    if (left->next())          // ok !
        left->next()->prev() = left;   // ok ! (4)

    if (e->prev())             // ok ! e prev is left prev is null
        e->prev()->next() = e; 

    e->next() = left;          // ok ! (5)
    left->prev() = e;          // ok ! (6) 
   }
```

Here the schema (sorry for the childish aspect ;-) ):

[image]

So the list is in fact fine.  The problem is that `ElemList` certainly contains a pointer to the head of the list .  And this pointer still points to the old first and now second element.  So the list is then no longer consitent.

## How to fix it ?

One way out, would be to make `move_element_left()` a member function of `ElemList`.  In this case you could take care of the special case where `e->left` becomes null, in which case you need to update ElemList's pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the updated code. You need to **change the head pointer if the left pointer points to head of double linked list**.

```
 //**head is the address of pointer of head of double linked list

            void move_element_left(Elem *e,Elem **head)
           {
            if(e->prev()==NULL)
              return;           //Left most ... so return

            Elem *left = e->prev();
            if(left==*head){
             *head=e;
             }

            left->next() = e->next();
            e->prev() = left->prev();

            if (left->next())
                left->next()->prev() = left;

            if (e->prev())
                e->prev()->next() = e;

            e->next() = left;
            left->prev() = e;
           }
```